# How can I get the name only to show in the MessageBox using C# windows form .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I have already a class that contains name and id and I'm also using lists method and including the name and id of each student.I'm also selecting a course from the combo box and selecting an index from the list box that contains names and id. The i.Name is generating an error, I have also tried writing All students.SelectedItem instead of i.Name ( That worked but It showed the name and id )
attached below is the screenshot of that [![enter image description here][1]][1]
This is my code below

```
 if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1 && Allstudents.SelectedIndex != -1)

        {

            var query3 = from i in prod
                         where i == Allstudents.SelectedItem
                         select i.Name;
            foreach(var i in query3)
            {
                var b = query3  ;
            }

            MessageBox.Show("The student" + i.Name +
                "Has registered in the course" + comboBox1.SelectedItem);
```

How Can I only show the name ?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehQ6K.png

Comment: The `i.Name` is generating an error in the `MessageBox.Show` parameter because there is no variable `i` in that scope. Did you mean to call the method inside of the foreach? Also are you sure you meant to do `var b = query3;` inside the foreach instead of `var b = i;`?

Comment: Well, I tried that and It didnt work as well.Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the split string method to split the selected string.

Assuming spaces in between, use the following code as a demonstration:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
    string[] s = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(' ');
    MessageBox.Show(s[1]);
}
```

[image]